# Want to use Space Bar followed by a key instead of C-key in Normal State of Evil Mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, evil-mode

I would like to be able to hit the space bar *followed by* another key as an alternative to hitting Ctrl and than the key in Normal State of Evil Mode.

For example, this is what I've started defining in my `.emacs` file:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map " ww" 'evil-window-next)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map " wr" 'evil-window-rotate-downwards)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map " wR" 'evil-window-rotate-upwards)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map " wo" 'delete-other-windows)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map " wn" 'evil-window-new)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map " wl" 'evil-window-right)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map " wh" 'evil-window-left)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map " wj" 'evil-window-down)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map " wk" 'evil-window-up)
```

From what I know so far, it seems as if I can only define a key sequence as a given function, and not as as something that wouldn't be used on its own such as Ctrl. Is there a general way of doing this so that the space bar followed by another key would be equivalent to any `C-"that key"` in Normal State of Evil Mode?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough about Evil to give you a specific answer, but you could try

```
(define-key function-key-map " " 'event-apply-control-modifier)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map " " nil)
```

Tho the `function-key-map` binding will only kick in if SPC is "unbound" in all other maps, so binding it to nil in `evil-normal-state-map` might not be sufficient.  Otherwise you can use `key-translation-map` instead of `function-key-map`, so the rewrite will take precedence to the normal SPC bindings, but then you'll need to figure out how to enable/disable this binding when enering/leaving Evil's normal state.

Comment: Tried it and only `key-translation-map` does the trick and not `function-key-map`. I guess I have to find a way to enable/disable the binding when going in and out of Evil's normal state like you said, so I can still type a space when I need to. Also, would there be a way to be able to bind to `function-key-map` first in Emacs's initialization so that it would be done before any other bindings?